# MAUI CollectionView show Thumbnail instead full size photo

Tags: photo, maui

I created a Collection View for a app that showing photo specific by self app captured.

When showing the original photo it very slow e.g. the size of 5MB~10MB may be too large for showing.

Is there any way that I can get or even create the thumbnail for preview?

I tried for using C# standard way but the Image.Save( MemoryStream in MAUI is Windows platform only ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I want to point out, that it is not a matter of choice.

Too big images will not be rendered, and you will see nothing but white space. (Learned that from testing it on Android.)

You can check this first:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/images?view=net-maui-7.0

I also use ImageSharp. (Despite the non-sense that happened recently, this is still a very good tool).

In any case, maybe it will be good to store the photo and the thumbnail separately, speaking of collection view, I do not think that it will perform well, if you need to mass-scale 5-10 MB photos. At least the devices I use cannot do this effectively.